# How to perform an action after all networking requests finished or one of them failed?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-networking

I have 4 API URL endpoints, in my main activity when the activity show, I will make 4 requests to each endpoint simultaneously. I want to make my request indicator (progress bar) to gone if all that 4 requests is finished successfully or if one of them failed with request code 4xx or 5xx.

So basically I want to perform some action after all requests finish or one of them failed?

In iOS development, I can easily use `DispatchGroup` to group some actions and do something after some condition. What is the common way to solve this in Android?

here is the code I use, for simplification, let say I have 2 method to make requests to the server. I am using retrofit:

first, to get products:

```
fun getProductsFromServer(customerID: String, type: String = "", categoryID: String = "" , completion: (errorMessage: String?, products: ArrayList<Product>?) -> Unit) {

            val lakuinAPI = RetrofitHandler.getInstance(LakuinAPI::class.java)
            val call = lakuinAPI.getProductData("1","0","0","100000000000",type = type,customer_id = customerID,categories_id = categoryID)

            call.enqueue(object: Callback<ProductData> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<ProductData>, t: Throwable) {
                    completion("Failed to make netwroking call : ${t.localizedMessage}", null)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<ProductData>, response: Response<ProductData>) {

                    val productList = ArrayList<Product>()

                    if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                        completion("Error: ${response.code()}",productList)
                        return
                    }

                    val jsonProductData = response.body() ?: return
                    val statusSuccess = jsonProductData.success

                    if (statusSuccess == "1") {

                        val products = jsonProductData.product_data
                        completion(null,products)

                    } else if (statusSuccess == "0") {

                        val errorMessageFromServer = jsonProductData.message
                        completion(errorMessageFromServer,productList)


                    }


                }


            })
        }
```

second, to get banners

```
fun getBannersFromServer(completion: (errorMessage: String?, banners: ArrayList<Banner>?) -> Unit) {

            val lakuinAPI = RetrofitHandler.getInstance(LakuinAPI::class.java)
            val call = lakuinAPI.getBanners()

            call.enqueue(object : Callback<BannerData> {

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<BannerData>, t: Throwable) {
                    completion("Failed to make netwroking call : ${t.localizedMessage}", null)
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<BannerData>, response: Response<BannerData>) {

                    val bannerList = ArrayList<Banner>()

                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                        completion("Error: ${response.code()}",bannerList)
                        return
                    }

                    val jsonBannerData = response.body() ?: return
                    val statusSuccess = jsonBannerData.success

                    if (statusSuccess == "1") {

                        val banners = jsonBannerData.data
                        completion(null,banners)

                    } else if (statusSuccess == "0") {
                        val errorMessageFromServer = jsonBannerData.message
                        completion(errorMessageFromServer,bannerList)


                    }

                }


            })




        }
```

and then those two methods will be used in Main Activity like this

```
private fun getProducts(type: String) {

        Product.getProductsFromServer(customerID = userData.id.toString(), type = type) { errorMessage, products ->

            errorMessage?.let {
                activity?.toast(it)
            } ?: run {

                val productList = products ?: ArrayList()
                setUpRecyclerView(type = type,products = productList)

            }


        }

    }


    private fun getBanners() {


        Banner.getBannersFromServer { errorMessage, banners ->

            errorMessage?.let {
                activity?.toast(it)
            } ?: run {
                val bannerList = banners ?: ArrayList()
                setUpImageSlideShow(banners = bannerList)
            }


        }
    }
```

so,  after calling `getBanners()` and `getProducts()` , I want to hide progress bar, when those 2 request is successful. if failed let say I want to show toast massage ? how to do that ?

java is ok

Comment: have a look on AsyncTask

Comment: "I will make 4 requests to each endpoint simultaneously" please show some summarized code of how you do that. are you using some lib other than those provided by Android itself to make your requests?

Comment: @kamyarhaqqani I have added the code to my question. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

For achieving this, using [**Anko**](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko) is the preferred way if you're using `Kotlin` for Android Development.

```
doAsync {
    // ...
}
```

You can achieve the same with [**AsyncTask**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask) too, and plus it's an `Android API`, not a language feature of `Java` or `Kotlin`. Use `AsyncTask` like this:

```
class someTask() : AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Void?): String? {
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute()
        // ...
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg text: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        // ...
    }

    override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
        super.onPostExecute(result)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Please follow this [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/os/AsyncTask#the-4-steps) to see how the task responds as the asynchronous task is being executed.

Comment: I have added the code to my question. to be honest I am confused how to add my code to that asynctask or doAsync anko. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this with Retrofit and Coroutines.

## Step 1 Create Retrofit Calls

```
interface MyApi{

    @GET("end-point}")
    suspend fun firstCall(): Response<YourModelClassForResponse>

    @GET("end-point}")
    fun secondCall(): Response<YourModelClassForResponse>

    @GET("end-point}")
    fun thirdCall(): Response<YourModelClassForResponse>

    @GET("end-point}")
    fun fourthCall(): Call<YourModelClassForResponse>


    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "bas url"
        operator fun invoke(): SmartFarmApi {
            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .build().create(MyApi::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

## Step 2 Call your APIs with Coroutines

```
    GlobalScope.launch { 
      val firstCall =  MyApi().firstCall()
      val secondCall=  MyApi().secondCall()
      val thirdCall=  MyApi().thirdCall()
      val fourthCall =  MyApi().fourthCall()
    }
```

Though using GlobalScope is not good idea, but just to make it quick I written it here, you can create the coroutine scope to make these calls. 
Again calling 4 different APIs parallel in a single activity or fragment is  I don't consider as a good idea. I think you should change your API and make everything in one call.

Hope this helps. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Retrofit but this should work:

create a publicly accessible array; after the completion or failure of each request add the status to this array;

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call<BannerData>, t: Throwable) {
                completion("Failed to make netwroking call : ${t.localizedMessage}", null)
                the_public_array.add("failure");
}
override fun onResponse(call: Call<BannerData>, response: Response<BannerData>) {
                val bannerList = ArrayList<Banner>()
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    the_public_array.add("failure")
                    completion("Error: ${response.code()}",bannerList)
                    return
                }
                val jsonBannerData = response.body() ?: return
                val statusSuccess = jsonBannerData.success
                if (statusSuccess == "1") {
                    the_public_array.add("success")
                    val banners = jsonBannerData.data
                    completion(null,banners)
                } else if (statusSuccess == "0") {
                    the_public_array.add("failure")
                    val errorMessageFromServer = jsonBannerData.message
                    completion(errorMessageFromServer,bannerList)
                }

            }
```

create a thread(in your activity) which runs a code that check that array all the time until it either contains one failed connection or 4 successful connections; then set the visiblity of your view to gone if this condition is met( in the ui thread);

```
Thread(Runnable {
    while(true){
        if(the_public_array.contains_four_success_status()||
                the_public_array.contains_one_failure_status()){
            this@MainActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable { 
                the_progress_bar.set_Visibility(Gone) 
            }) 
            break;
         }
    }
}).start();
```